# Send the mail using timer job in draft folder

Tags: timer-jobs, presence-indication

Have SharePoint Custom timer job using C#, It's already created and working perfect, current process - e-mails are going to user's Inbox. But I want like E-mail should go to Draft Folder of receiver.

To send e-mail Using code like below -

```
smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.Host = web.Site.WebApplication.OutboundMailServiceInstance.Server.Address;
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("email address", toEmail, subject, body);
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

May be we can use something to save e-mail at Receiver Draft folder rather using send option. These may be few lines of code change if you already did this type of task

Comment: Is this your test environment or is it live?

Answer (score 1):

If this is **YOUR TEST/DEVELOPER ENIVRONMEN**T, you can use the following method

In Web Application's web.config, change the `deliveryMethod` of the SMTP settings to `SpecifiedPickupDirectory` and give it a location to push the emails to.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory" from="no-reply@domain.com">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\Work\PROJECTS\Emails" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
    <defaultProxy />
  </system.net>
```

That’s it. Now, all emails will be pushed to the directory you specified. This won't send the emails to user's inbox instead push it into the directory. You can still use the same code for sending the emails.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i don`t have the "pickupDirectoryLocation" of each user`s draft box.

Comment: The pickupDirectoryLocation can be a shared directory within the Network.. It won't be for each user, it will be a single directory where all emails will be dropped.